# Scrapy, scraping price data from StubHub

Tags: python, scrapy, screen-scraping

I've been having a difficult time with this one.

I want to scrape all the prices listed for this Bruno Mars concert at the Hollywood Bowl so I can get the average price.

http://www.stubhub.com/bruno-mars-tickets/bruno-mars-hollywood-hollywood-bowl-31-5-2014-4449604/

I've located the prices in the HTML and the xpath is pretty straightforward but I cannot get any values to return.

I think it has something to do with the content being generated via javascript or ajax but I can't figure out how to send the correct request to get the code to work.

Here's what I have:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from deeptix.items import DeeptixItem

class TicketSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "deeptix"
    allowed_domains = ["stubhub.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.stubhub.com/bruno-mars-tickets/bruno-mars-hollywood-hollywood-bowl-31-5-2014-4449604/"]

def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "q_cont")]')
    items = []
    for site in sites:
        item = DeeptixItem()
        item['price'] = site.xpath('span[contains(@class, "q")]/text()').extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated I've been struggling with this one for quite some time now. **Thank you in advance!**

Comment: I think what you want is fetched from an API call that returns JSON: https://www.stubhub.com/ticketAPI/restSvc/event/4449604/sort/price/0?ts=1396358054406

Answer (score 1):

According to the chrome network console, there is a AJAX request that loads all of the info about the event, including ticket information.

You don't need scrapy at all, just `urllib2` to get the data and `json` module to extract ticket prices:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.stubhub.com/ticketAPI/restSvc/event/4449604'

data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))
tickets = data['eventTicketListing']['eventTicket']

prices = [ticket['tc']['amount'] for ticket in tickets]
pprint(sorted(prices))
```

prints:

```
[156.0,
 159.0,
 169.0,
 175.0,
 175.0,
 194.5,
 199.0,
 ...
]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks that helps but I'm trying to make a scraper do this for all events and I the API has a request limit. I'm looking into working with AJAX requests with scrapy for this and some other projects. I appreciate the response

Comment: I had created chrome addon for this to overcome from get block